# Why occurs a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when I use args4j in a batch built by mvn:assembly

Tags: java, maven, classpath

For various experimentations, I take care of a java project in [github](https://github.com/alepuzio/buildCSS.git).

After the Maven build, the program runs with a script bat.

Now I opened a branch because I would use the library [args4j](http://args4j.kohsuke.org/) to parsing the arguments.

The build works fine, the jars exist in the directory *lib*, but when I run I have this stacktrace of Exception

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/kohsuke/args4j/CmdLineException
>           at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2625)
>           at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2866)
>           at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1676)
>           at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
>           at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.kohsuke.args4j.CmdLineException
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>           ... 6 more

in bat I configured the classpath so that the args4j jar in in *lib*: this are the instructions of bat script

```
SET JAVA_DIR=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\
>CUT
"%JAVA_DIR%\java" -jar ".\lib\buildCSS-1.0.jar"  -cp ".\lib\" -conf "./conf/environment.properties"
```

I don't understand the deal of **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError**. The jar are present and linked by **-cp** option

Do you have any idea (and solution), please?

Comment: Check for version mismatch between the compiled and running classes, it should be same.

Comment: @TruckDriver I think it's no because I use that version of args4j in a standalone class in my Eclipse and I did'nt have any problem with same JDK. the mismatch will be showed by a __Unsupported major.minor version XX__ exception

Comment: no not jdk's version , I am talking about args4j version, the same (args4 jar version ) should be used to compile and run

Comment: @TruckDriver ok, yes. It's the same version, the  2.33. This is the depepndency in my pom. `<groupId>args4j</groupId>
<artifactId>args4j-site</artifactId>
<version>2.33</version>` . In effect I have a warning in class CmdLineException, but it exists in jar (I verified)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot combine `-jar` and `-cp` arguments on the command line.  If the `java` command sees `-jar` it treats everything after the jarfile name as application arguments, AND it ignores any earlier classpath arguments.

You have two choices:

- Use `-cp`, include the main JAR in the classpath, and put the full class name for the main class on the command line.
- Use `-jar`, and add a "Class-Path" attribute to the main JAR's manifest file listing all of the dependencies.

References:

- [The `java` command page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/java.htm#JSWOR624) - explains `-jar` versus `-cp`
- [The JAR file specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/specs/jar/jar.html) - explains the "Class-Path" attribute

Note: since you are building the JAR file using Maven, there are other options; for example

- Use the "Shade" plugin to create an executable "uber-jar" containing all of the dependencies in a single JAR.

Comment: The problem is present using only __-cp__ or __-jar__ as you suggests: I resolved using the plugin _Shade_ as you suggests at the end.  Thank you!

Comment: The most likely reason you had problems with *just* `-cp` was most likely that the classpath that you specified was incomplete, incorrect or had the wrong syntax.  You *should* be about to do it all three ways.